# Quadrants and sectors

Tags: circles

AOB is a quadrant sector of radius r cut from a circle of center O. A semicircle of center P is drawn outside of quadrant taking AB as diameter. What is the difference between area of whole geometry and that of quadrant?

[image]

I want the area of ACBD (the shaded part).
I proceeded as follows:

[image]

What next??

Comment: The entire circle with diameter $AB$ is outside the quadrant, unless you count the intersection with $O$ as "inside" the quadrant. And "whole geometry" is what? The entire circle plus semicircle? I would guess not, but we should not have to guess.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please help.

Comment: The diagram makes everything much clearer. The work you have done so far also is a big improvement to the question. Next time you might use MathJax for the formulas (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), but I have tried to answer this question based on the new information.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your calculations for the area of the quadrant sector
and for the areas of the two parts in which the sector is cut by the chord $AB,$
namely, the triangle $\triangle AOB$ and the remaining part $ADBP,$
which is called a *circular segment.* 
I also agree about the radius of the semicircle.

The shaded region $ACBD$ is a type of figure called a *lune.*

From the radius of the semicircle you should be able to find its area,
which is the combined areas of the circular segment $ADBP$ and the lune $ACBD.$
Then, knowing the area of the circular segment, you should be able to find the area of the lune easily.

This is actually a rather famous result in classical geometry.